# bluemix mobile cloud application

Tags: android, ibm-cloud

I am following the tutorial posted by IBM https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/mobile.html on how to create a mobile cloud app. 
I have created a sample application on the IBM console whose status says "Running"
I have downloaded the sdk's mentioned that tutorial and followed all the steps accordingly. 
But when i run the application i get the following errors:

```
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295): Process: com.ibm.bluelist, PID: 1295
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.mobile.services.core.IBMBluemix
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.ibm.bluelist.BlueListApplication.onCreate(BlueListApplication.java:111)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-10 00:07:11.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please can any one advice me on how to run the application.

Comment: It sounds like you are not correctly imported the sdk, but there is definitely not enough information to tell you what a fix could be. Are you using Gradle to organise your imports or are you referencing them directly from a download? I got it working using Gradle.

Comment: I downloaded the sdk and copy pasted the jar files into the build path of the project(added them into libs folder). ibmbluemix.jar, ibmdata.jar and 3 more jar files like that. Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added ibmfilesync.jar to your 'libs' folder as well as the mobile data .jar. Mobile data depends on ibmfilesync.

If issues persist navigate to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure it is configured correctly.